# Link errors after pod install followed by attempted uninstall

Tags: swift3, cocoapods

I installed 'CoreStore' using cocoapods. one of the installed source (GCD) had over 30 compilation errors. I attempted to uninstall the module by running pod install on a Podfile without the module. However this is resulting in a link error `ld: framework not found Pods_QwikFile
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` .

1. How do I attempt to edit the link commands in Build Settings
2. Is it easier for me to edit the Link file directly. If so where do I find the link file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Build Phases part of the Target, I found clear reference to pod. I deleted the 2 entries and that eliminated the link errors.